Cloudflare Tunnel with Kubernetes Istio and mTLS enforced
I am using Cloudflare Tunnel as a pod inside Kubernetes and that works great without Istio.
I have tried to apply Istio mesh by enforcing mTLS between the pods. I am also interested in enforcing egress rules for outbound traffic.
The flow would look like this:
browser -> Cloudflare Tunnel -> Cloudflare Pod -> Istio Sidecar -> Server Pod

I get this error:
GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 UC upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection_termination}
I need direction here because I am not sure how the Cloudflare Tunnel's traffic should enter the Istio mesh.
Do I need to setup an ingress gateway that works with Cloudflare Tunnel?
Do I need to setup an egress gateway or service entry that works with Cloudflare Tunnel using these firewall rules? https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/deploy-tunnels/tunnel-with-firewall/
Here is my deployment yaml for Cloudflare Tunnel. The routing rule in Cloudflare is configured to communicate with the network service of the server e.g. http://myserver:9000/
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cloudflared
  name: cloudflared-deployment
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: cloudflared
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyCPU: "100m"
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyCPULimit: "100m"
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyMemory: "128Mi"
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyMemoryLimit: "128Mi"
        proxy.istio.io/config: '{ "holdApplicationUntilProxyStarts": true }'
      labels:
        app: cloudflared
        version: v1
        pod: cloudflared
        network: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - command:
            - cloudflared
            - tunnel
            # In a k8s environment, the metrics server needs to listen outside the pod it runs on.
            # The address 0.0.0.0:2000 allows any pod in the namespace.
            - --metrics
            - 0.0.0.0:2000
            - run
          image: cloudflare/cloudflared:latest
          name: cloudflared
          env:
            - name: TUNNEL_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: myapp-secret
                  key: tunneltoken

          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              # Cloudflared has a /ready endpoint which returns 200 if and only if
              # it has an active connection to the edge.
              path: /ready
              port: 2000
            failureThreshold: 1
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10

Here is the service of the server, reachable within the service mesh at http://myserver:9000
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myserver
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      #      port = port connected to ingress
      port: 9000
      # targetPort = port on container
      targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: myapp

